# written jquery plugin use this or $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm reading document about writing a new jquery plugin but i'm so flummoxing when see that code:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify();
```

to create a new greenify function add to jquery. I really don't understand why don't use $(this) instead this. Please, any one help me understand this? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In this case `this` refers to the **jQuery object** on which the plugin is applied. It's got a prototype with all jQuery methods that can be inherited by your element (like `css`).

you can easiliy prove it by doing

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    console.log(this); // you will see a jQuery object in the console
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

As it is already a jQuery object, there's no need to double wrap it in $(). However, `$(this)` will also work but is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` to change the `this` object to a jQuery object. In your case, `this` will contain the `<a>` element that is being 'greenified', but only the DOM element. Since DOM elements don't have any methods like those built-in with jQuery (such as `.css()`), you'll first need to change it to a jQuery object for you to be able to work with it like this.